# Paperclip not saving images sometimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using paperclip with my rails app.
Sometimes it is working fine when I upload files and sometimes it is not working. I use it to upload images only like jpeg,png,gif,jpg etc.

No need to suggest me about versioning and configuration. It all working fine but sometimes it does not.

Anyone faced this problem and if faced then how you find solution for this ?

Comment: Is the problem occurring locally or in production? The file might be exceeding the server file size limit.

Comment: no, an app is not hosted on heroku. the problem is occuring on development and production but not on staginng environment. and @Sam, file limit also not exceeding. and i try to upload same image on all three environments but i get problem on two of them only except staging

Comment: I think it might be a paperclip issue? It's happening to me too.

Comment: @Andrei, can you please elaborate your problem ?

Comment: I am not sure, but I might've been running two unicorn servers in parallel, or a single corrupted one. I closed all of them and reran it, works smooth now.

Comment: I also suffer from a similar issue too and I think we should share our details so that we can figure out what's the cause. In my case, it tends to happen when users try to 'overwrite' the images he/she once uploaded, and some 'original' images are NOT saved despite `Paperclip` claiming they were; strangely, other images (specified in the :styles hash) are saved. I read on my log that `Paperclip` did delete the old image and then save the new one, but the new one is nowhere seen in the logged path. I use CentOS (for Rails) and Amazon S3 (for the image storage), incidentally.